# Symdony5.3 - How to pass parameters from a Controller to a Service because the service calls a repo query?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am working on a project where Symfony serves as API backend (with ApiPlatform) and Angular the Front End and the lead decided we will use Services and to create a function inside called updateData().

In my Service:

```
public function updateData(array $dates, Hotel $hotel): ?array
    {
            $bookings= $this->em->getRepository(Booking::class)->findAllByIdAndDate($id, $date);
    
            foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
                ...
             }
        ...
    }
```

In my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/update_data", name="update_data")
 */
public function index(UpdateData $updateData)
{
    $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository(Hotel::class);

    $date = new \DateTime('2021-06-13');
    $id = 1;
    $hotel = $this->em->find($id);

    $message =  $updateData->updateData([$date], $hotel);

}
```

My question is how can I receive the data here and pass the parameters from this controller to the service?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update the data for a specific hotel, you can use url parameters or query parameters to customize your controller.

for example, you could use a URL like this: `/update_data/1?date=2021-06-13`

Then your code would be using [Symfony route parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-parameters) and [parameter conversion](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#parameter-conversion).

Here is a quick example of what this would look like.

```
/**
 * @Route("/update_data/{id<\d+>}", name="update_data")
 */
public function update_data(Hotel $hotel, Request $request): Response
{
    // the $hotel variable is autoconverted using parameter conversion
    $date = new \DateTime($request->query->get('date'));
    
    $message =  $updateData->updateData([$date], $hotel);

    // rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: Hi @Florent Destremau, you are right. I totally forgot to create this controller with parameters. But can I forward them to my service?

Comment: It's right in the code you wrote: you inject your service in your controller, and then you call your function. see https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services

Comment: @SamBath did that help ? You can mark the question resolved if it did :)

Comment: yes. Thanks. I am sorry, I wasn't on StackOverflow these days and didn't think of marking it up